# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

> ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence in oracle when using sys_refcursor.

I am expecting list of employees in the cursor. In my real scenario I need to check the count of employees and if count greater than zero I should use the same  select statement. Instead of executing same select statement multiple times I tried the below code snippet. But I am getting Fetch out of sequence error in the output cursor.

My table:

[image: My table]

```
create or replace procedure sp_temp_1  (
var_job in VARCHAR2,
cur_custid out sys_refcursor
) 
AS

  /* Declare Ref Cursor */
  --cur_custid  SYS_REFCURSOR;

  /* Declare Type using Fields from the employees table. */
  TYPE t_custrec IS RECORD (
    firstname    temp_emp.firstname%TYPE,
    lastname     temp_emp.lastname%TYPE
  );

  /* Declare Record based off of Type */
  custrec   t_custrec;

BEGIN

  OPEN cur_custid FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT firstname
                   ,lastname
      FROM temp_emp
     WHERE JOB = var_job; /* Data Analyst does not exist forcing Zero Rows returned */

  LOOP
    FETCH cur_custid
      INTO custrec;
    EXIT WHEN cur_custid%notfound;
    ---looping happens
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('Num Rows: ' || cur_custid%rowcount);

  IF cur_custid%rowcount = 0
  THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Zero Rows Condition Met.  Opening Cursor.');
    OPEN cur_custid FOR
      SELECT '0' AS empid FROM dual;
  END IF;

END;
```

I am expecting list of employees , but the `sys_refcursor` is providing "fetch out of sequence error" in Oracle:

[image: Screen shot of my error]

Comment: This is a snippet of redacted code, with apparently nothing that would cause it to hurl ORA-01008. Consequently it is difficult for us to advise. You need to provide [a reproducible test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with table structures and sample data which demonstrates the problem you have. At the very least we need some code which actually throws the exception.

Comment: I have attached my full  code here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why SQL Developer is giving that error; it seems to be unhappy trying to display the bound out cursor. There error is coming from that output window though, not your code.

If you run exactly the same test block manually as a script from a SQL worksheet, with a client variable to bind the out cursor to, you don't get an error:

```
var cur_custid refcursor;

DECLARE
  VAR_JOB VARCHAR2(200);
  CUR_CUSTID sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  VAR_JOB := 'teach';

  SP_TEMP_1(
    VAR_JOB => VAR_JOB,
    CUR_CUSTID => CUR_CUSTID
  );
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CUR_CUSTID = ' || CUR_CUSTID);
*/ 
  :CUR_CUSTID := CUR_CUSTID; --<-- Cursor
--rollback; 
END;
/

Num Rows: 3


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print cur_custid
```

But you don't get any output either. The `print` shows the cursor result, but it's empty.

The problem really is that you have consumed the cursor within your procedure; after this:

```
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_custid
      INTO custrec;
    EXIT WHEN cur_custid%notfound;
    ---looping happens
  END LOOP;
```

you have, clearly, encountered `cur_custid%notfound`, which means there are no rows left in the cursor. There is no rewind facility, automatic or manual; so when the caller gets control of that out variable back, the cursor is still empty. Or if you prefer to think of it this way, the cursor pointer is still pointing past the end of the data - there are no rows left to consume. (Again, why the procedure execution wizard errors at that point is unclear.)

Your premise:

> I need to check the count of employees and if count greater than zero I should use the same select statement. Instead of executing same select statement multiple times I tried

... is flawed. You can do what you're doing, but as you've consumed the cursor you have to re-open it, which still duplicates the statement:

```
  IF cur_custid%rowcount = 0
  THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Zero Rows Condition Met.  Opening Cursor.');
    OPEN cur_custid FOR
      SELECT '0' AS empid FROM dual;
  ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line('Non-zero Rows Condition Met.  Re-opening Cursor.');
    OPEN cur_custid FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT firstname
                   ,lastname
      FROM temp_emp
     WHERE JOB = var_job; /* Data Analyst does not exist forcing Zero Rows returned */
  END IF;
```

In that case you really only need to do a single fetch in your loop, and exit immediately; or indeed don't loop at all, just do a single simple fetch. You only care about zero/non-zero, not the actual non-zero count.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76b989660f00fbed9df45315d47403af) with your original code, a new version with the second cursor opening, and a second new version with a single fetch. And slightly modified calling blocks to output the results via `dbms_output`.

It might be simpler to do just do an initial count, and decide which cursor to open.

It's odd that the two possible cursors have a different number of columns, incidentally. Presumably whatever is calling this is supposed to loop through the cursor, and if it sees a zero in the ID columns it knows there is no data? It would be much cleaner to just make *that* note whether it processed any rows. Then your procedure doesn't need any of this logic, it can just open the single meaningful cursor - if you really need a procedure to do that at all. (Your real scenario might be doing much more work than your example implies; in which case the count approach would still probably be more appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

When I use your code with my minor modifications I get no error.  Perhaps my working code can assist you?  Let me know if you have any questions or if I can assist further.

**Summary**

- Declare Ref Cursor
- Declare Type based off of the fields in my employees table
- Declare Record based off of Type
- Open Cursor and enter Loop
- Within Loop populate record using the values FETCHed by the Cursor.
- Using dbms_output show some output so we know it's working
- Last, if zero rows returned by the cursor OPEN Cursor again using different SQL.

**Employees Table**

[image]

**Code**

```
DECLARE

  /* Declare Ref Cursor */
  cur_custid  SYS_REFCURSOR;

  /* Declare Type using Fields from the employees table. */
  TYPE t_custrec IS RECORD (
    firstname    employees.firstname%TYPE,
    lastname     employees.lastname%TYPE
  );

  /* Declare Record based off of Type */
  custrec   t_custrec;

BEGIN

  OPEN cur_custid FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT firstname
                   ,lastname
      FROM employees
     WHERE JOB like '%Data Analyst%'; /* Data Analyst does not exist forcing Zero Rows returned */

  LOOP
    FETCH cur_custid
      INTO custrec;
    EXIT WHEN cur_custid%notfound;
    ---looping happens
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('Num Rows: ' || cur_custid%rowcount);

  IF cur_custid%rowcount = 0
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Zero Rows Condition Met.  Opening Cursor.');
    OPEN cur_custid FOR
      SELECT '0' AS empid FROM dual;
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . I have used the same code above . But still getting the error. I have added full code above , the screen shots of my table and screen shot of error. Please help me on this . Or if any alternative available to avoid multiple times of using same sql statement suggest that one also